# how do you use multiple previously created vectors that contain subcategories to make a new vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, regression

I have a dataset with multiple species with sexes for the species. I first divided the data set into vectors for each species to do an analysis at the tribe level between males and females, and I would now like to run an analysis at the genus level between males and females. To do so, I am running a regression for both sexes.

Since I have vectors for all the species, I tried creating a new object using those vectors.

ex.

```r
genus.females <- c(species1[species1$sex == "female"], species2[species2$sex == "female"], species3[species3$sex == "female"])
```

running this code came up with the error of 'genus.females' object not found.

Is there a better way to try to sort out the females of one genus?

this is an example of the vector I originally made for the species:
species1 <- tribe.df[tribe.df$species == "species1",]

Comment: Can you share some data using `dput()` or a built in data set that's similar, and code for how you're running the analysis? At first glance, check you're using the correct variable name: you've created `genus.females` but it looks like you've called it with a missing s `genus.female` somewhere

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like your code would make a vector called `genus.females`, not `genus.female`.

Comment: There was a typo in my question. I am trying to call genus.females